# Partially disassembling Sticky Shimano STI shifter for service

Tags: maintenance, shimano, shifter

There are a few questions floating around regarding sticky STI shifters and the standard procedure seems to be to flush with a load of WD-40 and relube with aerosol grease or similar.

My set is Ultegra 6500 series.

Having tried this with with unsatisfactory results I think I need to take more drastic action. It is clear there is still significant grime and gummed-up grease in the mechanism (excerbated no doubt by long-term lack of name plate). I figured the best method would be to remove the shifter from the bike and give it a good submersion in degreaser.

My idea was to leave the body on the bars and just remove the lever, which incorporates the mechanism by removing the pivot pin and brake/gear cables. The [tech docs](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Ultegra/SI_6C80D_001/SI_6C80D_001_En_v1_m56577569830621374.pdf) show this process but I'm slightly scared of tiny pieces flying everywhere and being unable to reassemble. It also requires a "return spring installation tool" which I do not possess.

Has anyone had experience with this? How tricky is it for a reasonably technically inclined person? Would I be better off just removing the bar tape and taking off the whole unit?

Comment: Its a pretty hard job, from what I hear - IIRC, there are people who specialize in refurbishing STI brifters, and I'd find one of those people and get them to do it, especially on Ultegra level gear.

Comment: @Batman The 6500 series is 9-speed and the outfit I'm familiar with that repairs Shimano brifters won't touch the 9-speeds.

Comment: Hm. I seem to recall there being problems with some of the 9 speed era, but now a days, Sora is the 9 speed group (and the brifters don't have the nice hoods that 105 and higher do).

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a 9-speed and a cursory google will produce many posts about sticky shifting problems on shifters of these era . I'm using the opportunity to upgrade to 10-speed and have ordered a new set of 105 5700 shifters to replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after studying the tech doc I took the plunge. It is actually not difficult and the only tools you need are some hex keys. I managed to successfully remove the lever assembly from the shifter for cleaning. Just don't try to disassemble any further than the doc instructs.

The bad news was that even after a thorough soaking in degreaser (which turned black from the grime) and relube, shifting performance has hardly improved, suggesting some mechanical issue. I think some new shifters are in order.

Reassembly for almost as easy, the only slightly tricky bit was getting the return spring in the right place without the official tool. A bit of poking with a pointy implement solved it though.

**Conclusion:** definitely a viable and effective way to clean shifters - if grease and grime buildup is the cause of stickiness.

Comment: Have you checked and replaced your cables and cable housing?

Comment: Yes, the cables are all only a few months old and I removed the them to detach the lever; so was testing the shifter without any cables in anyway.